# Translation: 深V

Tags: translation

Maybe this question is better suited for the English Language SE site, but anywho...

V here stands for V-Neck as in: v-neck t-shirt/v-neck blouse/v-neck sweater, etc.

深 is deep - or more accurately here 'low'.

so basically it's a super low-cut v-neck style of clothing - but is there a proper translation for this in English?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually kind of answered your own question: `深V` can be translated as [**"low cut"**](http://www.yandy.com/Low-Cut-Mini-Dress-with-Cinched-Ties-on-Sides.php). Alternative names for that style are [**"v neck"** or **"deep v"**](http://www.missguided.co.uk/dresses/v-neck-dresses) as @Sheng-DuanSun suggested, or the [**"deep plunge"** or **"plunge neck"**](http://www.missguidedus.com/aleena-lace-plunge-neck-puffball-dress).

I believe I've also heard it called the "*plunge v neck*".

Answer (score 12):

Well... 深V is not a formal Chinese word, this word was created by bra-producers.
Who are trying to emphasis that their bra can help you to squeeze a **cleavage**.

After that, some dress producers who are also making those dresses with very low V-neck revealing females cleavages say that their dresses are 深V too.

Anyway, in most cases, 深V is the word describing clothes that are able to show the female's chest or cleavage.

深V is female only, if you want to describe male's V-neck cloths, just use V領. Which means V-shape collar.

Comment: interesting explanation but you didn't really provide much of a *translation*, as such, which is what was asked for in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think "deep V" is close enough. If you googled "deep v dress/bra" most result are same as 深V meaning in Chinese.

Answer (score -2):

The neckline is so deep that almost the chest is exposed.

Comment: -1. Not a translation.